# Defining a new Odoo ORM model and creating new records inside a test

Tags: unit-testing, orm, odoo, odoo-15

I would like to define a new Odoo model and create a new record inside a test. Here is some example code demonstrating what I would like to accomplish:

```
from odoo.tests.common import TransactionCase
from odoo.fields import Char
from odoo.models import Model

class CreateModelInstanceTest(TransactionCase):
    def test_create_model_instance(self):
        class TestModel(Model):
            _name = "test.model"
            name = Char()

        self.env["test.model"].create([{"name": "Test"}])
```

However, the test fails with `KeyError: 'test.model'`. It seems that the model needs to be added to the registry first.

How can I add the new `TestModel` model to the registry from within a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some ideas on how to solve this from reading [`odoo/modules/registry.py`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/modules/registry.py) and [`odoo/models.py`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/models.py). This is how I got the test passing:

```
class CreateModelInstanceTest(TransactionCase):
    def test_create_model_instance(self):
        class TestModel(Model):
            _name = "test.model"
            name = Char()

        model_name = TestModel._name

        self.registry.models[model_name] = TestModel._build_model(
            self.registry, self.cr
        )
        self.registry.setup_models(self.cr)
        self.registry.init_models(
            self.cr, [model_name], {"module": "test"}, install=True
        )

        name = "Name123"
        instance = self.env[model_name].create([{"name": name}])

        self.assertTrue(isinstance(instance, TestModel))
        self.assertEqual(instance.name, name)
```

I'm not sure if this is the right/preferred way of doing it or if there is a more elegant, better solution as this seems very hacky. I also don't know if these `BaseModel._build_model`, `Registry.setup_models` and `Registry.init_models` methods and the `Registry.models` dictionary can be considered a stable interface, or if it could break in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation before diving into this.
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/backend.html#

You should also watch a couple videos on Odoo's module building.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwIniIlIrAc
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Az8G4Y5r3Xg

Edit:

Sorry, maybe I'm confused by what you are trying to accomplish.
This is how you should set up a test according to the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/testing.html).

```
class TestModelA(common.TransactionCase):
    def test_some_action(self):
        record = self.env['model.a'].create({'field': 'value'})
        record.some_action()
        self.assertEqual(
            record.field,
            expected_field_value)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

I'm specifically looking for a way to create a new model and use it *within a test*.

I *could not* find the answer to the question in the links that you included in your answer. Could you please add the answer to the question to your post here on stack overflow? For example, could you please show how to modify my example code or post a sample test case of your own?

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers for more guidance.

Comment: Responding to your edit: This new answer is closer to what I am trying to do except if you now define `model.a` within your `test_some_action` method (instead of elsewhere in the module), I predict you will get the `KeyError: 'test.model'` exception I mentioned in my initial post.